# Proof concerning non-existance of increasing function over a dense set

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering if it's possible to prove that if $S \neq \mathbb{R}$ is a dense set of real numbers then there does not exist a strictly increasing function $f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(S) = \mathbb{R}$. My friend asked me for help on this question and I'm not sure what to tell him. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see that now...Good question, +1.

Comment: @julien Sorry, didn't see that you'd deleted your comment. And thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $f$ be a strictly increasing function on $S$ and let $x\in\mathbb R\setminus S$. Then let $m=\sup_{y<x; y\in S} f(y)$. Show that $m\in\mathbb R$ (that is, $m\neq +\infty$) and that it is not in the image $f(S)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I think I see where you're going with it.

Comment: Mr. Andrews, why is it necessary to prove that $m \neq +\infty$? The set of numbers $y < x, y \in S$ are bounded above by $x$ so $m$ must be finite by the fact that $f$ is one-to-one, no?

Comment: I didn't say it was hard to prove that $m\neq +\infty$, but you definitely need to show that the $\sup$ is in $\mathbb R$ so that, after we prove that $m\notin f(S)$ you know that $m\in \mathbb R\setminus f(S)$ :)

Comment: And no, the real reason $m\neq +\infty$ is that there is a $z\in S$ such that $z>x$ and therefore by monotonicity, the set of values $f(y)<f(z)$ for all $y<x$ since then $y<z$. So the supremum is finite. @Decave

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks again for the help as always my friend.